# Get html file from a given url using javascript($ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  dataType: 'html',
  url: 'http://www.google.com/',
  success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

I am getting this error in the console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

What can I do to avoid this error? Please help.

Comment: You can use `YQL`

Comment: try with ` crossDomain: true`

Comment: crossDomain:true didn't work.

Comment: @ArunpandianM that is not what `crossDomain:true` is even for. Read the `$.ajax` docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the backend, you can proxy this request to the backend, i.e. using PHP:

```
// get.php
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);

// frontend JS
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  dataType: 'html',
  url: '/get.php?url=http://www.google.com/',
  success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

PHP will be able to fetch the data, as it's not checking CORS.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send cross origin requests because it is a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Its because google.com goes not have cross origin requests enabled. If you try a site that does like for example:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  dataType: 'html',
  url: 'https://cors-test.appspot.com/test',
  success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

Then you will get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of security problem while fetching another domain. 
Please check this
**["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)**